# Does restarting a Docker container "remember" initial run arguments?

Tags: docker

I ran a Docker container using a *very* (8 lines) long list of arguments:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
    -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
    -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
    -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
    -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
    -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/registry.crt \
    -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/registry.key \
    registry:2
```

I confirmed this was running via `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ff9c654bfc39        registry:2          "/bin/registry /etc/d"   2 days ago          Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

I then stopped this container via `docker stop ff9c654bfc39`. I then tried re-running the container by issuing the exact same `docker run ...` (8 liner) as I did the first time:

```
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "registry" is already in use by container ff9c654bfc39. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

So then I just tried `docker restart ff9c654bfc39` and that seemed to work, but I'm not 100% sure Docker "remembered" my 8 lines of arguments from when I initially ran the container. Any ideas as to whether it is remembering? If not, what's the proper restart command to include those 8 lines?

Comment: Have you tried re-starting it with a simple "docker start" command? According to the reference (https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/): "A stopped container can be restarted with all its previous changes intact using docker start. See docker ps -a to view a list of all containers."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As @gabowsky is explaining in the comments, yes, Docker will remember.

Using `start`, `stop` and `restart` will NOT destroy the container, hence remembering everything, including data (even between reboot of the host).
What `stop` does is to stop the process running inside the container. That's all.

Also, Docker store all the context, variables, etc... in an internal format. You don't have to specify command line arguments again.
To see what Docker knows about your container, you can run `docker inspect`.

On the contrary, `rm` will destroy everything, including none persisted data, and the container would need to be recreated again (Giving the arguments again this time).

As a final note, you should very much use names instead of SHA1 when referring containers in command line

Comment: Thanks @Aurelien Thieriot (+1) - regarding your statement "*you should very much use names instead of SHA1 when referring containers in command line*", can I ask why?!?

Comment: Well, there is probably no proof or ground for it but I found it much more convenient to work with. Taking into account that you will quickly start linking containers together, update and/or commit images. Running a command to find the SHA1 will be tedious.

Comment: Also, Docker generate awesome and funny random names